# Data is not Passing into SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, sensors

I am doing a project where I have to save the sensor data into SQL Server. I have created a coding for the sensor and SQL Server. I am able to `INSERT` the coding using POST (postman) but I was not able to pass the sensor data into SQL Server.

How can I pass the Sensor parameters into a T-SQL query? It would be great if someone could guide me to sort it out this issue.

```html
exports.add = function (req, resp, reqBody) {
    try {
        if (!reqBody) throw new Error("Input not valid");
        var data = JSON.parse(reqBody);
        var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(reqBody);
        if (data) {//add more validations if necessary
            var sql = "INSERT INTO arduinoData (Machine, StartTime, EndTime, LengthTime) VALUES ";
            sql += util.format("(%s, '%s', '%s','%s') ", reqBody.data.Machine, reqBody.data.StartTime, reqBody.data.EndTime, reqBody.data.LengthTime);
            db.executeSql(sql, function (data, err) {
                if (err) {
                    httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
                }
                else {
                    httpMsgs.send200(req, resp);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Input not valid");
        }
    } 
        catch (ex) {
        httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, ex);
    }
    
};


function vibrationStart()
{
 
    data = [{
        Machine : "Machine",
        StartTime : "StartTime",
        EndTime : "EndTime",
        LengthTime : "LengthTime"
    }];
    var jsonTable = { "table": [] };
    var startTime = getTime();
    console.log(startTime[0] + " " + startTime[1]);
    var startData = {
        Machine: Machine,
        start_time: startTime[0] + " " + startTime[1],
        day_night: startTime[3],
        active: "true"
    };

    const options = {
        url: serverURL,
        method: "POST",
        form: startData
    };

    
    request.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("Sent starting message!");
            sendBackupData();

        } else {
            console.log("CANT'T SEND");
            // Write to JSON file for backup if can't send to server
            fs.readFile("backup.json", "utf8", function readFileCallback(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                jsonTable = JSON.parse(data);
                jsonTable.table.push(startData);
                
                var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonTable);
                fs.writeFile("backup.json", outputJSON, "utf8", function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        }
    });

    return startTime[2];
}

function vibrationStop(startTimeUnix)
{
    
    // Should get:
    // - End time and date the vibration ended
    // - Total length of time
    // Will send the message, if there is network connection, once complete.
    // Will store message into a JSON file if there is no network connection.
    
   data = [{
       Machine : "Machine",
       StartTime : "StartTime",
       EndTime : "EndTime",
       LengthTime : "LengthTime"
   }];

    var jsonTable = { "table": [] };
    var endTime = getTime();
    console.log(endTime[0] + " " + endTime[1]);
    var endTimeUnix = endTime[2];
    var LengthTime = endTimeUnix - startTimeUnix;
    console.log("Length time: " + LengthTime);



    var endData = {
        Machine: Machine,
        end_time: endTime[0] + " " + endTime[1],
        LengthTime: LengthTime,
        active: "false"
    };

    const options = {
        url: serverURL,
        method: "POST",
        form: endData
    };

    request.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("Sent end message!");
            sendBackupData();
            

        } else {
            console.log("CANT'T SEND");

            // Write to JSON file for backup if can't send to server
            fs.readFile("backup.json", "utf8", function readFileCallback(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                jsonTable = JSON.parse(data);
                jsonTable.table.push(endData);
                var data = JSON.stringify(executeSql);
                var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonTable);
                fs.writeFile("backup.json", outputJSON, "utf8", function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        }
    });

}


arduinoBoard.on("ready", function () {
    
    // Main function that runs when Arduino is 'ready'
    
    console.log("Board ready!");
    var tilt = new johnnyFive.Sensor.Digital(8);
    var sensorCount = 0;
    var sensorFlag = false, prevSensorFlag = false;
    var startTime = 0;
    var sendEmailTimeout;

    // When sensor changes value
    tilt.on("change", function () {
        sensorCount = 0;
        sensorFlag = true;
        console.log("TILTING!");
    });

    // Continuously loops
    var timeoutValue = 250;         // Change timeout value later on.
    tilt.on("data", function () {
        // Sensor just started turning on
        if (sensorFlag & !prevSensorFlag) {
            prevSensorFlag = true;
           startTime = vibrationStart();
            console.log("Vibration started.");
            clearTimeout(sendEmailTimeout); // Don't send email if switch activated before 5 minutes of inactivity
        }

        // Sensor just turned off
        if (!sensorFlag && prevSensorFlag) {
            prevSensorFlag = false;
          EndTime =   vibrationStop(startTime);
            console.log("Vibration stopped.");

            sendEmailTimeout = setTimeout(sendEmail, userOptions.email_time * 1000); // Send email after 5 minutes of inactivity
        }

        // Sensor reaches timeout value
        if (sensorCount == timeoutValue) {
            sensorCount = 0;
            sensorFlag = false;
        }
        sensorCount++;
    });
});
```

Comment: I know nothing about node.js but I do know my way around SQL Server - and it seems to me that your code might be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Anyway, if you want to pass string representations of datetime values to SQL Server you better use the following format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - thanks for the info, i wanted to send the data into DB, whenever i send the data throught Postman, its working when i clicked post.. is there anyway to send the data without clicking any button..

Comment: As I wrote, I know nothing about node.js

Comment: Thanks for your kind response@ZoharPeled, I Started to learn Node js, could of weeks ago for my project, still i am learning it.. So i have no idea either.. but hopefully i will learn it soon..!